# What's the best way to mock a nested function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, jestjs

consider a function

```
exports.projectNotifyLaunch = (admin, functions) => {
  return functions.database.ref("/projects/{pid}").onCreate(snap => {

    const { title } = snap.val();

    const notification = {
      title: `${title} just launched!`,
      body: `We just heard about a new cryptocurrency project called ${title}`
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("premium", { notification });
  });
};
```

How should I mock deeply nested functions such as

`functions.database.ref("/projects/{pid}").onCreate(snap => {});`

or

`admin.messaging().sendToTopic("premium", { notification });`

in Jest? I want to fire off the `snap=>{}` callback and assert against the value of `notification`.

### I was able to make this work

This works but it's quite verbose. I'm wondering if there is a better way, or a type of testing I'm not aware of with Jest.

```
describe("send notification to premium users on new project", () => {
  // INPUTS
  const snap = {
    val: () => ({
      title: "Test Title"
    })
  };

  const functions = {
    database: {
      ref: () => ({
        onCreate: callback => callback(snap)
      })
    }
  };

  // outputs

  let topicStub = null;
  let notificationStub = null;

  const admin = {
    messaging: () => ({
      sendToTopic: (topic, notification) => {
        topicStub = topic;
        notificationStub = notification;
      }
    })
  };

  projectNotifyLaunch(admin, functions);

  test("title is correct", () => {
    expect(notificationStub.notification.title).toBe(
      "Test Title just launched!"
    );
  });

  test("topic is premium", () => {
    expect(topicStub).toBe("premium");
  });
});
```

Comment: You could improve that code by using jest.fn mocks instead -- that way you can assert that `x` function was called with `y` args

Comment: @jcollum I have been trying to achieve this for some time and haven't been able to get it to work. Could you please help me understand?